# Javascript, acerta sequência de números

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

Não sei o porque não está funcionando:

```
<input type="text" id="numero"/>
<input type="submit" id="adivinha" value="compare com meu segredo"/>
<script>
var segredo=[1,2,5,6,11,12,15,16];
var numero=document.getElementById("numero").value;
var botaoclicado=function() {
for(var i=0;i<segredo.lenght;i=i+1){
if(segredo[i]==numero){
alert("parabens, acertou");
return;
}
}
alert("errou");
};
var botaoadivinha=document.getElementById("adivinha");
botaoadivinha.onclick=botaoclicado;
</script>
```

Comment: Você tem como deixar mais claro o que você quer?

Comment: acho que poderia ser muito melhor na explicação assim fica mais facil

Answer (score 1):

Tinhas alguns erros nesse código. Desde `lenght` mal escrito, a ir buscar o valor da input.

Deixo aqui a solução com os erros corrigidos:

```
var botaoclicado=function() {
    var segredo= new Array(1,2,5,6,11,12,15,16);
    var numero=document.getElementById("numero").value;
    for(var i=0;i<segredo.length;i++){
        if(segredo[i]==numero){
            alert("parabens, acertou");
            return;
        }
     }
     alert("errou");
};
var botaoadivinha=document.getElementById("adivinha");
botaoadivinha.onclick=botaoclicado;
```

LINK [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/hq0y5sym/)

Answer (score 0):

"lenght" é na verdade "length", veja:

```
<input type="text" id="numero"/>
<input type="submit" id="adivinha" value="compare com meu segredo"/>
<script>
var segredo=[1,2,5,6,11,12,15,16];    
var botaoclicado=function() 
{    
    var numero=document.getElementById("numero").value; 
    for(var i=0;i < segredo.length;i=i+1){

        if(segredo[i]==numero){
            alert("parabens, acertou");
            return true;
        }
    }    
    alert("errou");
};
var botaoadivinha=document.getElementById("adivinha");
botaoadivinha.onclick=botaoclicado;
</script>
```

Comment: Oblrigado, porém tenho mais uma dúvida por que preciso colocar o true?